# How to encode any kind of file ("JPG", "PNG", "DOCX", "ZIP", "GIF", "MP3" ...) in BASE64 in android studio?

Tags: android, base64, encode

I need to do this encoding so that in the end I decode to the original file again, could anyone help?

Comment: Please explain what you have tried and what specific problems you have encountered.

Comment: `need to do this encoding` Which encoding?

Comment: Well, one of them is like fetching any file inside a folder inside the android directory, and so I can get a base64 String.

Answer (score 3):

You can use [commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-codec/) for encoding and decoding.

```
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;


byte[] encodedBytes = Base64.encodeBase64("YourResursesAsString".getBytes());
System.out.println("encodedBytes " + new String(encodedBytes));
byte[] decodedBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(encodedBytes);
System.out.println("decodedBytes " + new String(decodedBytes));
```

Comment: Okay, with this code and import should I create something on build gradite dependencies?

Comment: dependencies are:
compile group: 'commons-codec', name: 'commons-codec', version: '1.5'

Comment: Okay, I'll try and bring you an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to encode image:

```
private void generateBase64StringFromImage() {
    Bitmap bm = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.menu_circle);
    ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    bm.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos); //bm is the bitmap object
    byte[] b = baos.toByteArray();
    String encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
    Log.e("KEY2== ", encodedImage);
}
```